# Why can't I index an array by a list comprehension?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Why is it that a numpy array can be indexed by a list, but not by a list comprehension?

```
lst = np.array(lst = ["a","b","c","d"])

ind = [i for i in range(4) if i%2 == 0]

# Indexing by the list works
lst[ind]

Out[28]: 
array(['a', 'c'], 
      dtype='|S1')


# Trying to use the list comprehension without storing it in an object first does not

lst[i for i in range(4) if i%2 == 0]

  File "<ipython-input-29-6256b805fa19>", line 1
    lst[i for i in range(4) if i%2 == 0]
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: That's not a list comprehension. You probably want `lst[[i for i in range(4) if i%2 == 0]]`. Your syntax just isn't valid Python.

Comment: May I ask why are you using numpy array for string items? Isn't Numpy supposed to be used for numbers?

Comment: @tglaria I'm not using it for strings, this is just an example

Comment: @tglaria That's a perfectly decent way to store strings provided that they have a constant length. Numpy also supports a number of vectorized operations on string arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need an extra set of brackets to "contain" the list comprehension:

```
lst[[i for i in range(4) if i%2 == 0]]
```